# Italian Citizenship through Jus Sanguinis

Tags: citizenship, italy

Sorry to bother you! I'm a fifteen year old girl living in America. My great-grandmother was Italian, and at some point in her life she became an American citizen. I don't know when, or if it was before or after she gave birth to my grandmother. Everyone else in my great-grandmother's family were Italians. I speak decent Italian, as well as Spanish and German. What exactly do I need to acquire Italian citizenship through Jus Sanguinis? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The part about whether she naturalized before or after giving birth to your grandmother is important, because naturalizing in the US would cause her to lose Italian citizenship, so it can only be passed on to your grandmother if the naturalization was after giving birth to your grandmother. You need to go research this in your family records.

Also note that transmission of Italian citizenship from the mother to the child could only happen since 1948. Prior to that, it could only be transmitted from the father. I don't know how long ago your grandmother was born, and how long ago the next-generation parent was born, but if any of those was before 1948, those links cannot be used.

Comment: I've heard that you can still have your claim approved if you sue for sexual discrimination. http://www.icapbridging2worlds.com/italian-dual-citizenship-services/descendants-of-women/ This website claims that it has been done many times.